# Visual Studio copy/paste into Outlook with standard formatting?

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, copy-paste, color-scheme

I have custom settings in Visual Studio that include a dark background. Copy/pasting to Outlook produces a crime against eyeballs with a dark background in code on a white background of the mail.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can paste code in standard VS formatting (NOT unformatted text from paste special, and not paste with my custom VS formatting)?

(Alternatively, does anyone know a quick way to switch between themes in VS? Thinking that could also work...)

Comment: Same problem now with VS 2012 dark theme

Comment: Why don't Microsoft fix this?

Comment: Still a problem in VS 2013. Here's the uservoice for this issue http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3516267-improve-dark-theme-text-copying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following blog post details how to address this issue in VS2012:

http://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/copy-and-paste-formatting-with-visual-studios-dark-theme/

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the closest I got was using [CopySourceAsHtml](http://copysourceashtml.codeplex.com/) which also allows you to define custom css styles for that copied html. I peeked at the css styles when copying code from the default VS theme and copied them over.

Got me 90% there which is good enough - no black code backgrounds on white email backgrounds!

Comment: Sorry, I know it's been a long time. Could you please post the style you used to make it default VS style?

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this now... the CopySourceAsHtml add-in only supports up to Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: "Copy as HTML" (different tool, similar name) supports up to VS2012, which is a bit more helpful

Answer (score 1):

[This free VS Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/98fef791-eb65-4cdf-bf84-077b98c234cf) (named "Copy As HTML") allows you to choose the background color when copying to clipboard:

> This is a lightweight tool that allows you to copy code from the Code
>   Window and convert it into HTML while preserving syntax highlighting,
>   indentation and background colour.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't support VS2013+ at this staage

Answer (score -2):

This add-in adds a command to copy in plain text: [VSHelper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VSHelper.aspx)

Comment: It is clearly stated in the question that he does not want to copy plain text.