# dark theme in visual studio makes code difficult to read in emails and other notes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I like to use a dark theme (it's a slight variation of zenburn) but I have a problem when I want to copy and paste a snippet of code into some notes, documentation or an email in that you are pasting dark backgrounded text (generally) into a white background document.

This makes is ugly and hard to read.

One workaround I have for this is to paste it into linqpad first which uses the classic VS colouring.

Is there an easier way or even a VS plugin that means the code gets copied with a different theme applied?

**Update:** Looks like this has already been asked here: [Visual Studio copy/paste into Outlook with standard formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867555/visual-studio-copy-paste-into-outlook-with-standard-formatting)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio copy/paste into Outlook with standard formatting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867555/visual-studio-copy-paste-into-outlook-with-standard-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You could install [Microsoft's Productivity Power Tools Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef). It allows HTML copying of the code and will include your dark background when you paste into an email client that supports HTML formatting, or Word, etc.

It does many other things too, but you could turn all the other options off if you don't want them, and just leave the HTML copy feature enabled.